# Awk printing multiple times istead just one as is expected

Tags: shell, awk

I have a shell script

```
logstash_out=`echo "green" | /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {codec => json} }' --log.level=error`
echo "_______________________________"
echo $logstash_out
echo "_______________________________"
msg=`echo "$logstash_out" |  awk -F 'input:' '{print $1}'`
echo $msg
echo "_______________________________"
msg1=`echo "$logstash_out" |  awk -F '{' -v q='{' '{print q$2}'`
echo $msg1
echo "_______________________________"
```

The output of the above script is :

```
_______________________________
Sending Logstash logs to /opt/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties The stdin plugin is now waiting for input: {"host":"medium","@timestamp":"2020-11-19T10:32:03.860Z","message":"green","@version":"1"}
_______________________________
Sending Logstash logs to /opt/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties The stdin plugin is now waiting for {"host":"medium","@timestamp":"2020-11-19T10:32:03.860Z","message":"green","@version":"1"}
_______________________________
{ { {"host":"medium","@timestamp":"2020-11-19T10:32:03.860Z","message":"green","@version":"1"}
_______________________________
```

Issues :

1. I want to split the json part, when I try the first awk script i.e

   msg=`echo "$logstash_out" |  awk -F 'input:' '{print $1}'`

It removes the "input:" word from the variable $logstash_out instead of splitting it.Same can be seen in the output.

2. If I try the second awk script i.e

   msg1=`echo "$logstash_out" |  awk -F '{' -v q='{' '{print q$2}'`

It prints the variable "q" three times. Can anyone help me to explain what I am doing incorrectly.

Expected Output:

```
{"host":"medium","@timestamp":"2020-11-19T10:32:03.860Z","message":"green","@version":"1"}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in form of code, keep it up. Could you please do let us know sample expected output n your question? Also do you have `jq` tool which is recommended ideal tool for handling jsons by experts with you in your system(or you can install it in your box)?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I just want the output as  {"host":"medium","@timestamp":"2020-11-19T10:32:03.860Z","message":"green","@version":"1"}

Comment: Kindly update your question with sample input and expected output please, comment are not meant for showing samples/codes, thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `echo "$logstash_out"` **with double quotes**. There's no reliable way to tell what's in there from the information posted in the question. E.g. missing newlines in the displayed output would change the behaviour of the `awk` commands.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following `awk` solution:

```
awk -F "[{}]" '{print "{" $2 "}"}'
```

Let us know if this helps

Comment: thanks but this did not help as it is giving following output                                      {} {} {"@version":"1","message":"green","@timestamp":"2020-11-19T13:47:11.758Z","host":"medium"}